# Network interface with same ip address as gateway on other interface

Tags: linux

I have a linux device with two network interfaces one of which provides an access point dhcp and website and the other connects to the internet.
The first has a static ip 10.0.0.1 which I cannot change. The second nic uses dhcp to connect to the existing network. I have no control over the settings for that network. Traffic on the first nic is handled within the device and does not have to be bridged to the other network interface. Other processes on the device have to access the internet through the second nic.

This works fine until the gateway/router for the second nic uses the same subnet as the first nic 10.0.0.0/24 and thus the same  ip for the gateway/dns etc as the ip for the first nic. No connection to the internet is made because all traffic to the gateway is routed over the `lo` nic. Also the website on the access point is not reachable.

To be clear: both networks should be completely independent. Clients connecting to the first nic will have no connection to the second and vice versa. The device uses the first nic to provide a configuration website. In a similar fashion as your typical home router. The second nic is used by the device to perform its main function which needs a connection to the internet.

How can I resolve this and properly separate the two?

I tried the following things:

- Removing the 10.0.0.1 route from the local table. This is a bit cumbersome because I have to script this. Also it only solves the part where the device is able to connect to the internet. The local website is still unreachable.
- Add the first nic to a network namespace. This kind of seems to work except that I cannot do that because the first nic is actually a virtual interface on a wireless interface and you can only add the underlying interface and not individual virtual network interfaces..
- I tried reading up on VLANs but I am not sure if that will work or how to make it work
- it tried looking into the settings in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf but so far have not found a way.

Comment: Err, use `10.1.0.0/24` on the first nic instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with 10.0.0.1. Also it is at all possible that the gateway for the second nic will have 10.1.0.1 and then i'm in the same boat.

Comment: Can you explain "Why" you need the one interface to provide DHCP, and the other to connect to the internet? Why can you not use the same NIC to provide services and internet access? Please give some more context to your situation as well.

Comment: The first NIC serves an access point with a setup website. (Similar to home routers). Therefore it needs to be accessible on a stable document ip hence the 10.0.0.1. 
The second is used by the device to connect to the internet. It needs configuration before it can do that so I cannot use the second NIC for the setup website.
Users connected to the access point should not have a connection to the internet through the device

Answer (score 1):

If the two NICs are plugged into the same network or VLAN, the problem is that you cannot use the same IP twice on a single network.

If the two NICs are meant to be plugged into different networks, then you should not have one network subnet re-used in another part of the network, unless you are putting NAT into place between them.

If neither of these fit, please provide more context on what the networks are for.

Comment: NAT in between would be OK, even no connection is fine. They are really separate and don't need to interact

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have control over what subnet your gateway gives out over DHCP. Make sure it doesn't overlap with your upstream network.

Having two interfaces with the same IP in different broadcast domains will still be an issue for the local machine that has those two IPs. As stated above, simply prevent this from ever happening by specifying a different subnet via your DHCP server and assigning an IP to that internally facing interface that is within your specified subnet.

Comment: While I do have control I cannot change the ip address for the first NIC and thus the subnet. It is specified that is has to be 10.0.0.1 also every other choice could still lead to a situation where the gateway for the second nic has the same ip/subnet